# R shiny: RenderDataTable and RenderLeaflet

Tags: r, shiny

I am very new in R (shiny), but learning fast. So, my apologies for a probably easy question... I am having some issues with the combination of RenderDataTable and RenderLeaflet.

I will first give you some code I have prepared already:
First of all, a dataframe and initial codes:

```
#three packages to plot maps    
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#generate a dataset of species, distributions, densities and references to literature
df<- data.frame(
Number_Total = sample(c("5", "6", "1", "3")),
Species = sample(c("Ilione trifaria", "Pherbellia argyrotarsis", "Euthycera seguyi", "Ilione trifaria")),
Article= sample(c("Verbeke (1950)", "Verbeke (1950)", "Vala (1999)", "Vala (1999)")),
X = sample(c("1", "2", "3", "4")),
Y = sample(c("3", "2", "1", "1")))

#just make sure coordinates and numbers are numeric
df$X<-as.numeric(df$X) 
df$Y<-as.numeric(df$Y) 
df$Number_Total<-as.numeric(df$Number_Total)

#for the map you need to save dataframe as RDS
saveRDS(df, ".sample_data.rds")
```

Then, the UI (which is OK in my opinion?):

```
ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Map and plot table at same time"),  

          sidebarLayout(
            sidebarPanel(
              selectizeInput('species', 'Choose species', 
                             choices = df$Species, multiple = FALSE, 
                             options = list(placeholder = 'select species'))
            ),
            mainPanel(
              leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 600, height = 300),
              dataTableOutput("table")
              )
          )
)
```

And the server:

```
  server <- function(input, output, session) {  
  map_data <- reactive({
    df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })

  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 1, lat = 1, zoom = 5) %>%
      addCircles(lng = map_data() %>% pull(Y), lat = map_data() %>% pull(X), weight = 10, 
                 radius = sqrt(map_data() %>% pull(Number_Total))*15000, 
                 popup = map_data() %>% pull(Species))

  })



  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    df %>%
      filter(df$Species == input$distinct_vars)  %>% 
      select(Article) %>%
      unique()
  })
  }
```

And ofcourse, the best line of all:

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This code gives you an interface in which you can plot the species on a map, that works fine.

But, it should also give a DataTable underneath the map, in which the literature references are listed?! I am quit sure the error is on the server-side, but I cannot find when I failed?

It is a big question, but, I hope it is an easy one to solve.
Thank you, very much!!!
Jonas

Comment: what is `input$distinct_vars`? It's not specified as input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `distinct_vars` wasn't specified as input. Second, I added the dataset creation as a new `reactive` in order not to load it every time. If you read it from rds, you can put the code reading the file into the reactive function `dataset()`.

Here's a slightly different version of your code. Looks like it's working:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

#generate a dataset of species, distributions, densities and references to literature

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel("Map and plot table at same time"),  

            sidebarLayout(
              sidebarPanel(
                selectizeInput('species', 'Choose species', 
                               choices = df$Species, multiple = FALSE, 
                               options = list(placeholder = 'select species'))
              ),
              mainPanel(
                leafletOutput("CountryMap", width = 600, height = 300),
                dataTableOutput("table")
              )
            )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {  

  dataset <- reactive({
    df<- data.frame(
      Number_Total = sample(c("5", "6", "1", "3")),
      Species = sample(c("Ilione trifaria", "Pherbellia argyrotarsis", "Euthycera seguyi", "Ilione trifaria")),
      Article= sample(c("Verbeke (1950)", "Verbeke (1950)", "Vala (1999)", "Vala (1999)")),
      X = sample(c("1", "2", "3", "4")),
      Y = sample(c("3", "2", "1", "1")))

    #just make sure coordinates and numbers are numeric
    df$X<-as.numeric(df$X) 
    df$Y<-as.numeric(df$Y) 
    df$Number_Total<-as.numeric(df$Number_Total)

    df
  })

  map_data <- reactive({

    df <- dataset()


    df[df$Species %in% input$species, ]
  })

  output$CountryMap <- renderLeaflet({

    leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% 
      setView(lng = 1, lat = 1, zoom = 5) %>%
      addCircles(lng = map_data() %>% pull(Y), lat = map_data() %>% pull(X), weight = 10, 
                 radius = sqrt(map_data() %>% pull(Number_Total))*15000, 
                 popup = map_data() %>% pull(Species))

  })



  output$table <- renderDataTable({
    dataset() %>%
      filter(Species == input$species)  %>% 
      select(Article) %>%
      unique()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you, very much appreciated! 
Especially your comments on getting the dataset as reactive.
Best wishes,
Jonas